# OpenGL vs Unity Android live wallpaper

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es-2.0, live-wallpaper

I created Android live wallpaper using canvas but it seems to be quite slow in performance. I was thinking of shifting towards OpenGLES 2.0 but it is very difficult to code from scratch because there are a lot of animations. I want a sincere opinion which one is the best for making live wallpapers Unity or OpenGLES 2.0, also give a basic idea whether unity slows down the wallpaper or not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can create a live wallpaper using Unity. At least not easily, Unity is not intended for this. Usually a live wallpaper consists of a service, a *Settings* activity, and some sort of resource which defines your live wallpaper. Everything you create in Unity will be <strike>compiled</strike> <strike>packaged</strike> magically transformed into an activity with a launcher. This means your Unity "game" will not be in the wallpapers list, but in the apps list. Also, by default it will run in the front, not in the back of a home screen like a live wallpaper would do.

To make it work as a wallpaper would require a lot of altering to what Unity outputs when building, because Unity does not offer any live wallpaper settings. That seems like a lot of work. Also, it seems a bit [overkill](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=overkill) to use a game engine or OpenGL for a live wallpaper.

Keep in mind that you should not try to create a >30 fps live wallpaper, because that would drain an Android device's battery pretty fast. If I were you I would try to make the wallpaper look good with <30 fps. Try not to have fast animations, pre-render 3D stuff and optimize what you already have.

Comment: There is a plugin in unity named "Uni2LWP" that can convert any unity project into a live wallpaper project for eclipse. I implemented basic particle effects with simple animations and it seems to be working perfectly fine. I read what you said very carefully and if neither Unity nor OpenGL then what should i be using for live wallpapers i used simple canvas but it was way too slow.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using Unity.

Unity engine is pretty good for highly-visual stuff, with its visual editor, good asset import pipeline and tons of stuff on Asset Store that would help to boost your development. It'd be very hard to beat it performance-wise. There are other game engines that you could use for live wallpapers, but it'd be a much more tedious task.

The negative side of using Unity is that it might be somewhat heavy - it's expected to have an minimal APK of around 9 MB in size This doesn't really matters if you have a resource-heavy live wallpaper, though.

What makes it possible, is that recently I've released *uLiveWallpaper* - a Unity asset that makes it possible to create live wallpapers for Android using Unity 5. It is well-tested and reliable, creates projects for Android Studio, complete with placeholder code to get you started.

Check it out:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ulivewallpaper-develop-android-live-wallpapers-with-unity-5.375255/